# Hooks setter not setting state with object variable

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to build a simple tree menu with react. I found [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZGqdrNZroYg) showing exactly what I want to achieve ([his Codepen](https://codepen.io/mikedane94/pen/aXLpMv)). I was able to implement his approach, but then, out of curiosity, tried to replicate the same using hooks. I ended up with this (simplified):

[my Codepen](https://codepen.io/xbartolo/pen/wvMJGWj)

```
const App2 = () => { 
  const [selectedOptions, setSelectedOptions] = React.useState({});    

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log(selectedOptions);
  },[selectedOptions]);

  const updateSelection = (sel) => {
    console.log(sel)
    setSelectedOptions(sel);
  }

  return (
      <div className="wrapper">
        <h1>Toppings</h1>
        <OptionsList 
          options={options} 
          onChange={updateSelection}
          selectedOptions={selectedOptions} 
          />
      </div>
  );  
}

const OptionsList = ({ selectedOptions, onChange }) => { 
  const handleCheckboxClicked = (selectedOptionId) => {   
    if(selectedOptions[selectedOptionId]){
      delete selectedOptions[selectedOptionId];
    } else {
      selectedOptions[selectedOptionId] = {}      
    }    

    onChange(selectedOptions);
  }
  
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => (handleCheckboxClicked("chicken-id"))} >
        Set Chicken
      </button>      
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App2 />, document.querySelector('#app'));
```

The problem is `setSelectedOptions(sel)`, inside the function updateSelection is not doing absolutely anything (and of course useEffect is not being fired).
I'm not able to figure out why. I put a console.log just above it to check whether the variable ("sel") was okay or not, but it seems fine. I tried hardcoding the value of "sel", {chicken-id: {}}, and it works when I do so.

Comment: `setSelectedOptions` is working indeed (see console logs). The point is that you are never using such options in your code - try to render something in your `OptionsList` component depending on `selectedOptions`, and you'll see the changes.

Comment: useeffect is not triggered because there is no change in the object reference. try this setSelectedOptions({...sel});

Comment: But if the state is being updated, useEffect should fire which is not the case. What the console is showing is the console.log in updateSelection, not the one in useEffect.

Comment: Hi Karan, that seems to work! Will test with the full code tomorrow. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are directly mutating the state object:

```
    if(selectedOptions[selectedOptionId]){
      delete selectedOptions[selectedOptionId];
    } else {
      selectedOptions[selectedOptionId] = {}      
    }    

    onChange(selectedOptions);
```

In both outcomes you alter the state object and then set it as itself, so naturally the `useEffect` will not fire as the setter has effected no actual change. You have to be careful of doing this in React as it's an easy way to end up with stale values. Re-renders are only triggered when there is a difference between the current state and the value passed by the setter, not whenever the values of the state change, for whatever reason.

A comment suggested that you use spread - `...` - to destructure the state object so that you can set it as itself, but this seems like a bit of an anti-pattern to me especially as it leaves the state mutation in place. If you want to delete an entry from a state object then a general approach would be to clone the object first, mutate the clone, then set that as the new state:

```
    const clone = Object.assign({}, selectedOptions);
    if(clone[selectedOptionId]){
      delete clone[selectedOptionId];
    } else {
      clone[selectedOptionId] = {}      
    };
    onChange(clone);
```

A word of caution though, any nested objects inside this object will retain their references to the original state and could still mutate it. You would have to clone these nested objects as well to avoid the issue.